# How to move 'get UI element button' [+] to right side panel

Tags: xcode, xcode11

How can I add the get UI element button to the right side panel of my screen like shown in this image:

[image: get UI element tab located in right side panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that's not possible to go back how it was before.
But a workaround is to dock a window of the library by simply option+click the "+" sign.